# Consulta utilizando eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una tabla que almacena facturas, estas facturas se clasifican en varios tipos : A14, B16 , C18 y cada una tiene un campo de monto.

Quisiera saber la forma mas conveniente en eloquent de obtener este resultado: Necesito obtener todas las facturas de todos los tipos, a excepcion de las B16 y solo sacarlas en caso de que su monto sea igual o  mayor a 50,000.

He tratado esto:

```
$facturas = Factura::where('cliente_id', $id)
    ->orWhere(function($q){
        $q->where('clasificacion', 'B16')
            ->where('monto_fact', 50000.00)
            ->orWhere('monto_fact', '>', 50000.00);
    })
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

Comment: @BetaM cuando ejecuto esa consulta me trae todas las facturas sin importar las condiciones que le puse.

Comment: @BetaM cliente_id es básicamente busco las facturas de un cliente en un cierto rango de tiempo.

Comment: @BetaM acabo de modificar el código para que sea mas entendible.

Comment: Es idea mía, o se lee: "donde el cliente = Cliente id **OR** ---?? Creo que el OR está haciendo que te devuelva más registros... Debería leerse: `where Cliente = ClienteId AND Clasificacion <> B16 AND MontoFactura>=50000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un `where` para *obtener todas las facturas de todos los tipos, a excepcion de las B16*:

```
where('clasificacion', '<>', 'B16')
```

Y un `orWhere` para obtener también las B16 *en caso de que su monto sea igual o mayor a 50,000*.

```
orWhere(function($q){
    $q->where('clasificacion', 'B16')
        ->where('monto_fact', '>=', 50000);
})
```

Pero cuidado, ese `orWhere` sólo debe afectar al `where` que excluye a las B16, por lo tanto deberás agrupar esas condiciones para que no afecte a otras (como la que condiciona la columna `cliente_id`):

```
$facturas = Factura::where('cliente_id', $id)
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('clasificacion', '<>', 'B16')
            ->orWhere(function($q){
                $q->where('clasificacion', 'B16')
                    ->where('monto_fact', '>=', 50000);
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

**NOTA**:

> Siempre debe agrupar las llamadas `orWhere` para evitar comportamientos inesperados cuando se aplican ámbitos globales.

Referencia:

Database: Query Builder [Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping).

Comment: muchas gracias. Me sirvió mucho!